# Cannot Insert Date in MongoDB compass

Tags: database, mongodb, date, nosql, mongodb-compass

[image][image]

I am new to MongoDB. I am trying to insert a date using document in the mongoDB compass. But whenever i try to insert it, I get the "insert not permitted error". I tried to fix it and search in the internet about it, but i couldn't get any information about it.

I also tried ISODate, but it resulted in the same error. Can you guys please help me with this?

Comment: Using MongoDB Compass _"ADD DATA"_ --> _"Insert document"_, you could use something like `{"date": {"$date": "2023-10-17T00:00:00.000Z"}}` or `{"date": {"$date": {"$numberLong": "1234567890000"}}}`.

Comment: Using MongoDB Compass' builtin `mongosh`, you could also use something like `use Test1` followed by `db.Test1.insertOne({"date": new Date()})`.